# Fastapi + jinja2 : how to check if user is authenticated in jinja to template conditions

Tags: oauth-2.0, jinja2, fastapi

#### How can we check is user is authenticated and populate any value

'''{% if user.is_authenticated %}{{'Hello'}}{% endif %}'''

Answer (score 0):

After setting up `AuthenticationMiddleware` like in the [documentation](https://www.starlette.io/authentication/), you can access `Request.user.is_authenticated`, which should be a boolean.

The 'request' variable should be passed to your Jinja template.

In your Jinja template, use an `if` block to display 'Hello' if the user is authenticated.

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Hello</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: When I tried using middleware like below getting an error "h11._util.RemoteProtocolError: illegal request line" Added as "app.add_middleware(HTTPSRedirectMiddleware)" "@app.middleware("http") followed by function"